# PikePdf returning incorrect page count, how to get correct page count?

Tags: python, pdf, pikepdf

I am using pikepdf to open a pdf file and get the page count for that file. My code is roughly:

```
import pikepdf
with open(file_uri, "rb") as input_pdf:
    input_reader = pikepdf.Pdf.open(input_pdf)
    page_count: int = len(input_reader.pages)
```

Very rarely a pdf file will give the incorrect number of pages. For example, I have a file that when opened on my laptop in a PDF viewer is 39 pages. `pikepdf` gives a page count of `47` pages. The metadata when I click `Get Info` in the file browser states 39 pages.

Unfortunately, I cannot share the file as it has protected information.

How would I make sure I get the correct page count from pikepdf? I've used other Python PDF libraries (eg pypdf) in the past but they have errors opening python files sometimes.

Comment: Recommending PyMuPDF: it has automatic PDF repair during open and should always deliver the right page count.

Comment: Adding a comment that pikepdf actually had the correct page count. I re-saved the pdf using linearization=True from pikepdf and got all 47 pages. I think there is an issue with how the pdf was created/saved but am not certain yet.